# How to write onPause() and onResume() method for Camera preview using Texture View

Tags: java, android, camera, textureview

I copied an android custom  camera making code. I used camera api 1 and TextireView for layout.

I'm stuck in `onPause()` and `onResume()` method, any suggestion to handle this methods . Other methods like `onSurfaceTextureUpdated()` are ok. But because of pause and resume the original phone camera app stops, saying camera not available. I don't want to use surfaceView and surfac holder for camera implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure in your Activity that is using the Camera that in the onPause() method you release the camera. In the onResume method is where you should start the Camera. These two events should be completely independent of your method of displaying the preview really.